# Fill combobox when calling from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm very new to C# and I have a problem filling a combobox when calling the method from another class. My source is like this

class 1

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
    uc1.fill_cbb();
}
```

class 2

```
public void fill_cbb()
{
    cbb_table.Items.Add("Text1");
    cbb_table.Items.Add("Text2");
    cbb_table.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

When I do it that way the combobox is empty.

Comment: And what is the problem??

Comment: Is this winforms or asp.net?

Comment: I'm I wasn't finished when I saved it. The combobox is empty.

Comment: OK - as Tim said, is this ASP or winforms?

Comment: It's ASP. Strange thing is the combobox is getting filled when the code is called in public void UserControl1_Load() method

Comment: OK, I think you also need to call DataBind on the control after adding the items. if that does not work, then you may need to bind the control on the postback as well

Answer (score 0):

if it is Asp please take care to the event IsPostBack

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not calling the method from another class. I suppose *UserControl1* is your custom user control, and that the "class 2" you mentioned is a userControl1.

The code would work as it is, but you are calling it on the wrong instance of that control.

In your btn_login_Click method, you are generating a totally new instance of UserControl1. You are of course allowed to do that, which is why Visual Studio would never mark it as an error, but *uc1* will not be the control that actually sits in your form.

Let's say in your form you have named the control "cbxOptions". Then in the button click event, you have to write

> cbxOptions.fill_cbb();

instead, if that combobox is also of type UserControl1. Then it should work just fine.

Warning, car analogy: It's like when you want a new paint job on your car. Then you buy a new car of the same model and take that to the paint shop, get it painted, then bring it to the junkyard and get it crushed. Your old car will still have the same old color of course.